# streaming live audio in android with MP

Tags: java, android, streaming, android-mediaplayer, http-live-streaming

i'm trying to stream live audio form the internet using setDataSource, however when I add the url it says it's an unhandled exception.. any ideas whats wrong here?

```
String daytonPolice = "http://relay.radioreference.com:80/691484064";
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mp.setDataSource(daytonPolice); // It will not take the string of my url
mp.prepareAsync();
mp.start();
```

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you are calling start() right after calling prepareAsync(). You need to set an onPreparedListener:

```
String daytonPolice = "http://relay.radioreference.com:80/691484064";
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }
});

mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mp.setDataSource(daytonPolice); // It will not take the string of my url
mp.prepareAsync();
```